# How can I change the password in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I wanna change Django password without using the default view. I passed the `PasswordChangeForm` to the view but I didn't know how to post it.

```
class UpdateUserView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'test.html'
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['PasswordChangeForm'] = PasswordChangeForm(self.request.user)
        return data

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        change_pw = User(password=request.POST.get('id_new_password1'))
        change_pw.save()

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change a password, using [**set_password()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords):

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='john')
>>> u.set_password('new password')
>>> u.save()
```

In your view:

```
...

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = self.request.user
    user.set_password(request.POST.get('id_new_password1'))
    user.save()
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

...
```

Instead of a `post()` method , I would use `form_valid()` method:

```
def form_valid(self,form):
    user = self.object
    user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get("id_new_password1"))
    user.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Password cannot be altered just like any other fields because they needed to be encrypted before saving. You need to use the [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords) method which will take care of the encryption part.

Your code will be like this...

```
class UpdateUserView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'test.html'
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['PasswordChangeForm'] = PasswordChangeForm(self.request.user)
        return data

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        u = self.request.user
        u.set_password(request.POST.get('id_new_password1'))
        u.save()
        
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: This is not the same answer as mine?

Comment: Yeah, it seems we submitted almost the exact same time.

Comment: The view users.views.UpdateUserView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

that's what i got

Comment: @daraq, your post method must return this `return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)`. See my answer.

Comment: i will try that , by the way the django change password form have two fields (id_new_password1 and id_new_password2 for confirmations ) i should get both of them ?

Comment: im sorry for annoying but im just junior on django .. it logged me out and i can enter with the new or old password too